# sync.WaitGroup doesnt waits

Tags: concurrency, go

May be I can not see obvious thing, what am I doing wrong:

```
func printSize (listOfUrls []string){
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(listOfUrl))
    for _, myurl := range(listOfUrls){
        go func(){
               body := getUrlBody(myurl)
               fmt.Println(len(body))
               wg.Done()
           }()    
    } 
    wg.Wait()
}
```

If I remove wg and go, I receive the size of each url body correctly. If I do it as in above, it prints zeroes almost instantly. The getUrlBody() takes time to execute sometimes minutes.

Answering comment: I also tried it this way, to be sure, and it demonstrate same behaviour.
I found the error was in getUrlBody and main() function...

```
func printSize(listOfUrls []string) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(listOfUrls))
        for _, myurl := range listOfUrls {
          go f(myurl, &wg)
        }
    wg.Wait()
}

func f(myurl string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    body := getUrlBody(myurl)
    fmt.Println(len(body))
    wg.Done()
 }
```

Comment: You have a racecondition in your code on `myurl`. You should copy it by passing it to the closure. Otherwise, it will probably mostly refer to the last element in your range in all of your goroutines.

Comment: Yes, I added 2nd version which I guess correct, but does not works too.

Comment: If listOfUrls has say 4 urls, It prints ("Getting url:") from getBodyUrls four times, and then it prints zeroes for length also four times...  In theory it should print "Done url: " from getBodyUrls, and print correct size...

Comment: sorry I thought that it would be enough, the getUrlBody is really huge to post, but I guess problem must be there,  I will simplify it by rmeoving things, and edit the head post.

Comment: It's a shame... error was very clear (if look) in getUrlBody... :-( I am so sorry. Thank you for pointing me on my closure/variable that was also source of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the goroutines are sharing the single `myurl` variable. See https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines for more information.

Change the code to:

```
func f(listOfUrls []string){
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  wg.Add(len(listOfUrl))
  for _, myurl := range(listOfUrls){
    go func(myurl string){
           body := getUrlBody(myurl)
           fmt.Println(len(body))
           wg.Done()
       }(myurl)    
  } 
  wg.Wait()
}
```

or

```
func f(listOfUrls []string){
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  wg.Add(len(listOfUrl))
  for _, myurl := range(listOfUrls){
    myurl := myurl
    go func(){
           body := getUrlBody(myurl)
           fmt.Println(len(body))
           wg.Done()
       }()    
  } 
  wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Please, if my edit with addition to start topic, makes sense?